# Not able to test Sagepay Repeat Payment

Tags: php, payment-gateway, opayo

I am using test environment and I am able to do simple payment but when I trying to test repeat payment then I am not able to understand 4 mandatory fields
which are

1.RelatedVPSTxId

2.RelatedVendorTxCode

3.RelatedSecurityKey

4.RelatedTxAuthNo

Pls someone explain that what I need to put in these fields and also I already read this tutorial

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/21071/download-document/SHARED_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf?token=D4jfiGwtOMRN8Hu7oASnlhGCGV98PojRSXSfxSY77G4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 4 fields all relate to an original transaction that you would like to repeat i.e. you are using the details of a successful payment already made (e.g. through the checkout page of your online store) to perform the repeat transaction against (although obviously it can be for a completely different monetary value).

If you want to perform repeat transactions then you'll need to store these values from the initial transaction in a database so you can retrieve them as required to process the repeat:

1. **VPSTxId** (posted back to you from SagePay when the original transaction was made)
2. **VendorTxCode** (created by you to make the original payment)
3. **SecurityKey** (posted back to you from SagePay when the original transaction was made)
4. **TxAuthNo** (posted back to you from SagePay when the original transaction was made)

Comment: Brilliant Man, Thanks, Let me try to do so